# Typescript type confusion. Variable doesn't mind type

Tags: typescript

If i have:

```
var greeter: Greeter = new Sausage();
```

And both the `Greeter` class and `Sausage` class have the same functions and properties in them, the variable greeter will quite happily be filled up with a `Sausage`... How can i stop this?

For example, the following code compiles fine :(

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

class Sausage {
    size: number;
    name: string;
    greeting: string;

    constructor() {
        this.size = this.SausageLogic(); 
    }

    private SausageLogic(): number {
        return this.size * 3;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, ";
    }
}

var greeter: Greeter = new Sausage();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript uses a structural type system. Even though you didn't say `Sausage extends Greeter`, `Sausage` is still a *subtype* of `Greeter` because it has at least all the same members that `Greeter` does. Notice that anything you can do with a `Greeter` (access its `greeting` property or invoke its `greet` method) is legal to do with a `Sausage`.

If you were to add a method `foo` to `Greeter`, or remove the `greeting` property from `Sausage`, for example, that last line of code would become an error. Any `private` member is also enough to cause a structural mismatch (unless `Sausage` was explicitly derived from `Greeter`).

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 See also [typescriptlang.org: Handbook → Type Compatibility](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#type-compatibility)

Comment: What is the benefit of this loose type structural nonsense... Or is it a compromise because of JavaScript's failings?

Comment: Is there any built in way to keep this type check from failing compilation... I see many situations where this could cause issues... Other than manually adding a unique id as a property to each class thus showing error. If not... Is there another language I can use that does check this type and show errors? Is the typescript compiler open source so I can change it?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 yes to your last question (see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/274)

Comment: @xmojmr - Mega helpful, I hope it comes into fruition